# Package is not installed in raspberry pi 3 B

Tags: php, package, raspberry-pi3

When I try to install php5 and apache2 in raspberry Pi to use an internal database which is used for IoT further using below command:

```
Sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

I get the following error:
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-10.0

[image]

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with python or mysql, only php.

Comment: Can you please help me how to handle this error(php5)
Thank you.